# input file - read contents before submit

Tags: javascript, html, dom, file-upload

I'm trying to find out if there is clean, cross browser way to peek at the contents of a file waiting to be uploaded through an html input element.

The intention is to be able to select a csv file then clientside read the first few lines so I can format it and allow the user to select which columns should be mapped to which predetermined expected value.

If the web app is expecting a data file and wants a firstname, surname, email and role; the data can ben in any order to allow the csv file to change without updating the upload code.

I've found ActiveX solutions but I was hoping to find something that either wraps this functionality cross browser or a more modern solution

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader

Comment: Available with Web File API. See http://caniuse.com/#search=File%20API and http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Comment: I knew there was something like canIuse, just didn't know what it was call. Good to know there is something I can use, even though I can't use it on the corporate ie8 build